# college football analysis - TypeError when obtaining star player counts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to get counts on all star players in the dataset `teams_join_recruits['Stars']`.

I get the `TypeError` in the second to last cell when I run the code block. Let me know if more information is needed.

Minimum Reproducible Result checked.

Code:

```py
# importing pandas
import pandas as pd
        
# setting display options
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000); 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000); 
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
    
# reading the datasets
teams_join_recruits = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sjohn\OneDrive\Documents\D195 Capstone\DataFrames\teams_join_recruits.csv', index_col=False)

df_teams_typeerror = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sjohn\OneDrive\Documents\D195 Capstone\DataFrames\df_teams_typeerror.csv', index_col=False)
    
df_recruits_typeerror = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sjohn\OneDrive\Documents\D195 Capstone\DataFrames\df_recruits_typeerror.csv', index_col=False) `
        

# a look at the datatypes and any missing data    
df_recruits_typeerror.info()
df_teams_typeerror.info()
teams_join_recruits.info()
```

joining teams to recruits - this concat operation with the bracketed dfs, `[df_teams2013_2020, df_cfb_recruits]` was completed in another notebook, I just included it as a comment for clarity.

```py
# concat operation to join the dfs
teams_join_recruits = pd.concat([df_teams2013_2020, df_cfb_recruits], ignore_index=True)

# Using just the recruits dataset (@Max888) 
# pivot_table() get the Star counts    
# four arrays with four elements each - I will need to adopt this to my data -  2500+ rows
    
# importing pandas    
import pandas as pd
    
#create the dataframe    
players = pd.DataFrame({
'year': [2010,
         2010,
         2010,
         2010,
         ...],       
        'stars': ['5',
         '5',
         '5',
         '5',
         ...], 
        'team': ['Florida State',
         'Florida State',
         'Miami',
         'Miami',
         ...],
        'player': ['Dorial Green-Beckham',
         'Johnathan Gray',
         'Stefon Diggs',
         'Jameis Winston',
          ...]})
```

```py
#pivot operation
table1 = pd.pivot_table(players, values='player', index=['stars'], columns=['team', 'year'], aggfunc= 'count')
print(table1)
# TypeError in this cell
        
        
# using example from @Prudhviraj
       
# 'Team A', B ect will need to be replaced with my 2000+ football team names, same for 'Player 1'
        
#importing panda library    
import pandas as pd
        
# Step 1: Initialize counts for star players in the teams dataset
teams_data = {
'team': ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C'],
'year': [2013, 2014, 2015],
'4_5Stars': [0, 0, 0],
'2_3Stars': [0, 0, 0]
}
teams_df = pd.DataFrame(teams_data)
        
star_counts = {}
for _, row in teams_df.iterrows():
    key = (row['team'], row['year'])
    star_counts[key] = {'4_5Stars': 0, '2_3Stars': 0}
        
# Step 2: Iterate over the recruits dataset and update star player counts
recruits_data = {'player': ['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3'],
                 'stars': [4, 5, 3],
                 'year': [2013, 2013, 2014],
                 'team': ['Team A', 'Team A', 'Team B']
                 }
recruits_df = pd.DataFrame(recruits_data)
        
        
for _, row in recruits_df.iterrows():
    key = (row['team'], row['year'])
        if row['stars'] >= 4:
            star_counts[key]['4_5Stars'] += 1
        elif row['stars'] >= 2:
            star_counts[key]['2_3Stars'] += 1
        
# Step 3: Update the teams dataset with star player counts
for _, row in teams_df.iterrows():
    key = (row['team'], row['year'])
    teams_df.loc[(_, '4_5Stars')] = star_counts[key]['4_5Stars']
    teams_df.loc[(_, '2_3Stars')] = star_counts[key]['2_3Stars']
        
print(teams_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df_recruits = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sjohn\OneDrive\Documents\D195 Capstone\DataFrames\df_recruits_typeerror.csv')
df_teams = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sjohn\OneDrive\Documents\D195 Capstone\DataFrames\df_teams_typeerror.csv')

# Assuming here to use Year_Played and not Year_Recruited
# Change it in line below if needed
year_col = 'Year_Played'
stars_counts = df_recruits.groupby(['Team', year_col])['Stars'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)

# Add '2' and '3' columns to form '2_3', '4' and '5' columns to form '4_5'
stars_counts['2_3'] = stars_counts.get(2, 0) + stars_counts.get(3, 0)
stars_counts['4_5'] = stars_counts.get(4, 0) + stars_counts.get(5, 0)

# Rename the columns to have .Stars
stars_counts.columns = [f'{col}.Stars' for col in stars_counts.columns]

# Reset index and rename column to do merge later with df_teams
stars_counts = stars_counts.reset_index(drop=False)
stars_counts = stars_counts.rename(columns={year_col: 'Year'})

# Merge to df_teams
df_teams = pd.merge(df_teams, stars_counts, how='left', on=['Team', 'Year'], suffixes=['_DROP','']).fillna(0)

drop_cols = [col for col in df_teams.columns if col.endswith('_DROP')]
df_teams = df_teams.drop(columns=drop_cols)
```

**Sample Output: First 20 rows of 970**

```
print(df_teams.head(20).to_string())
                Team       Conference  Year  Games  Win  Loss  Off.Yards.per.Game  Yards.Per.Game.Allowed  Touchdowns  Touchdowns.Allowed  1.Stars  2.Stars  3.Stars  4.Stars  5.Stars  2_3.Stars  4_5.Stars
0             Akron               MAC  2013     12    5     7               342.0                   397.0          31                  44      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
1           Alabama               SEC  2013     13   11     2               454.1                   286.5          65                  23      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
2           Arizona            Pac-12  2013     13    8     5               458.5                   401.1          57                  39      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
3      Arizona State           Pac-12  2013     14   10     4               457.3                   372.4          69                  48      0.0      2.0      2.0      0.0      0.0        4.0        0.0
4          Arkansas               SEC  2013     12    3     9               357.2                   413.4          30                  49      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
5    Arkansas State          Sun Belt  2013     13    8     5               407.8                   413.1          48                  43      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
6   Army West Point   FBS Independent  2013     12    3     9               387.3                   410.8          38                  49      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
7            Auburn               SEC  2013     14   12     2               501.3                   420.7          73                  41      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
8        Ball State               MAC  2013     13   10     3               477.1                   413.8          64                  39      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
9            Baylor            Big 12  2013     13   11     2               618.8                   360.3          91                  41      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
10   Boston College               ACC  2013     13    7     6               367.2                   429.0          43                  48      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
11    Bowling Green               MAC  2013     14   10     4               459.4                   321.4          62                  29      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
12          Buffalo               MAC  2013     13    8     5               394.7                   382.8          51                  40      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
13              BYU   FBS Independent  2013     13    8     5               493.6                   378.8          47                  33      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
14       California            Pac-12  2013     12    1    11               453.6                   529.6          32                  72      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
15  Central Michigan              MAC  2013     12    6     6               341.1                   405.2          35                  43      0.0      0.0      3.0      1.0      0.0        3.0        1.0
16       Cincinnati               AAC  2013     13    9     4               472.1                   315.6          57                  34      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
17          Clemson               ACC  2013     13   11     2               507.7                   356.7          69                  37      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
18         Colorado            Pac-12  2013     12    4     8               369.9                   468.0          36                  58      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
19             Duke               ACC  2013     14   10     4               426.1                   418.0          60                  48      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0        0.0
```